# MySQL-Select start and end of week along with average of a column (week-by-week)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get average of a column `player_count` week-by-week over the past 6 weeks. But the problem is that I also want the start and the end of the week date which corresponds to a specific average.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT AVG(player_count) as average, 
  updated_at, 
  updated_at + INTERVAL WEEKDAY(updated_at) + 7 DAY as EndDate 
FROM `gtan_servers` 
WHERE server_short_name = 'FiveRP' 
GROUP BY WEEK(updated_at) 
ORDER BY updated_at DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

The `updated_at` column is intended to be taken as start of the week and `EndDate` is going to be taken as end of the week in which a specific average of the player count is provided.

But this query is not working correctly regarding the week dates. I can fetch the average yes but the week dates are not being fetched correctly. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an expression that *truncates* an arbitrary date to the first day of the week in which it occurs.  That is, it returns `2017-05-21` (Sunday) if you give it `2017-05-24`

This expression does that, assuming your weeks start on Sundays. [Here's an explanation.](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/)

```
    FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -1, 7))
```

Then you need to use that as a `GROUP BY` expression and a WHERE expression.

```
SELECT AVG(player_count) as average, 
  FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(updated_at) -MOD(TO_DAYS(updated_at) -1, 7)) week_beginning, 
  FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(updated_at) -MOD(TO_DAYS(updated_at) -1, 7)) + INTERVAL 6 DAY week_ending 
FROM `gtan_servers` 
WHERE server_short_name = 'FiveRP' 
  AND updated_at >= FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -1, 7)) - INTERVAL 6 WEEK
GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(updated_at) -MOD(TO_DAYS(updated_at) -1, 7)) 
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

The `WHERE` automatically filters out records from your table that are too old for your report.

This query gets a little repetitive, but it works nicely.

You could create a stored function like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TRUNC_SUNDAY$$
CREATE
  FUNCTION TRUNC_SUNDAY(datestamp DATETIME)
  RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
  COMMENT 'returns preceding Sunday'
  RETURN FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -1, 7))$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then your query becomes more readable:

```
SELECT AVG(player_count) as average, 
  TRUNC_SUNDAY(updated_at) week_beginning, 
  TRUNC_SUNDAY(updated_at) + INTERVAL 6 DAY week_ending 
FROM `gtan_servers` 
WHERE server_short_name = 'FiveRP' 
  AND updated_at >= TRUNC_SUNDAY(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 WEEK
GROUP BY TRUNC_SUNDAY(updated_at) 
ORDER BY TRUNC_SUNDAY(updated_at) DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

If your weeks start on Mondays change the `-1` to a `-2`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed. Keep helping the community man.